# Sorting of nested objects in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, rxjs

Below is a URL.
https://jsonurl.com/ocr-

Each key contains an object.
Inside there is also an object.
All I want in sort these with respect to positive values found in the Islamabad Serena Hotel from largest to smallest.

I have tried some stuff but I failed I need to expert to jump in and guide me through.

Sorting of nested objects in reacts js.

Comment: Could you explain with an example.. your JSON is huge and needs explanation of the JSON as well

Comment: I want to sort on the basis of the "positive" that can be found in the "Islamabad Serena Hotel" object.

Sorting from largest to smallest.

Comment: you have `{
"Restaurant":{},
"Room":{},
"Time":{},
"Service":{},
"Hotel":{},
"Staff":{},
"Food":{},
"Breakfast":{},
"Place":{},
"Stay":{}
}` as your object.. each `key` has set of hotel names.. each hotel has `"Restaurant":{
"Islamabad Serena Hotel":{
"Neutral":60,
"Positive":224,
"Negative":17,
"Overall":301,
"Review":{}
},
"Gesher HaZiv TravelHotel":{},
"Average":{}
}`.. how your end result should be.. atleast give an example for that

Comment: It needs to be the same as the current just needs to be sorted on the basis of positive. 

Also, we just have to sort on the basis of the first hotel i.e "Islamabad Serena Hotel" in every object wrt to the positive key found In that object.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest an algorithm, you can code it hopefully. I'm assuming it doesn't matter if `Positive` value is repeated in different objects.
Write a function which would:

- Go through all the objects, extract the value of `Positive` and store these values in an array, say `positiveValues`
- Now sort this array with any sorting algorithm you like.
- Create a new array, say `sortedObjects`
- Iterate the sorted array `positiveValues`, for each value iterate through the original objects and find that value.
- Once found, push that object in newly created array `sortedObjects`